# Mount directory in docker image that is build remotely

Tags: docker, remote-access, file-sharing

I have a robot which exists in the same network as my host pc. the robot is powered using Jetson Nano and has ubuntu installed. I have a docker image that I usually build on the robot using `-H` flag i.e `docker -H robot.local build --network="host" -t test .`. Now i want to mount a directory from my host to the docker image. the directories aren't being shown in the docker. To make it clear, there are 3 environments here:

**1 - Host PC**

**2 - Ubuntu running on Jetson board**

**3 - Docker environment**

The images are built on **2** from **1**. The issue is that mounting a directory from **1** to **3** doesn't work.I tried using `docker -H robot.local run --rm -it -v "$(pwd)/src":/root/ --net=host  ID_CONTAINER`

I want to work in my host pc on a code that changes instantly inside the docker container

Comment: Is the volume available from where the docker container is running?

Comment: Docker doesn't have any way to transfer files across the network (aside from pushing and pulling complete images); that command is mounting the directory on the remote system.

Comment: @Alex no it's not

Comment: @JohnC. you will need to be able to access this volume on the machine docker is running in order to bind it to the container.  Is there a way you can create a network volume on your PC and mount it on the machine where docker is running?